# I was wondering how i could make this CSS work on only some products on Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I found a code that worked to disable the link to access the single product page. Some of the products are upcoming and i want to have ads displayed as "products" in the shop.

This is the code:

```
#popular .woocommerce ul.products li.product {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I tried to replace #popular with the page id, like .page-id-2365 and so on, but it do not work.

I would be really thankful if someone could help me writing it so i could add several pages.

Thanks in advance :)

I have tried:

```
#popular .woocommerce ul.products li.post-id-2365 {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And with changes like li.post-2365 instead of post-id, and removing #popular but sadly it do not work.

Comment: the `<li>` element contains a class containing the post (product) id. So use `#popular .woocommerce ul.products li.post-1`, where 1 = ID

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. Sadly i could not get either li.post-2365 or li.post-id-2365 to work.

Comment: have you looked at the html code in detail? inspected the element? checked if there are differences in classes between the different li elements?

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will look at the HTML.